# Rendering variables from state stops working if innerHTML is modified

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Having an issue where a 3rd party library is setting `document.body.innerHTML`, and that causes `setState` to stop seeming to work fully.  In React tools in chrome and when debugging it updates the state object correctly, but the rendered output does not update.

Cannot figure out what is going on here, no error occurs, stepping through the debugger nothing stands out to me.  At first I was also using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but the issue seems to be occurring on normal jsx value injection too.

Example here, if you modify the value of `const ModifyBody = true;` to false and it works as expected, but with the `document.body.innerHTML =` it doesn't update.

https://codepen.io/eibwen/pen/gjBxrZ

---

Just to restate it, its a third party library doing the `body.innerHTML`.  Specifically its a library to [create a medium.com-like popup when selecting text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selection-popup), if you happened to know a library that could do this with better compatibility with TypeScript/React I'd be all ears on that too

Comment: Wow...any library that sets body.innerHTML would break a lot of pages....not just react. Would nullify all addEventListener except for window, document or body ones

Comment: The library is appending to the `body.innerHTML` would that still nullify all event listeners?  Oh because it is basically converting the body.innerHTML to a string, appending a new string to it, then parsing that back into DOM?  If so that probably is the answer, React is using event listeners to update all the DOM structure in some fashion

Comment: Right ... if it does `body.innerHTML += 'widget html'` the whole body will get stringified like you said and all original dom node references are broken. They should have used an append approach